# Recursive functions and lists

Tags: python-2.7

Im still studying old tests and got truble with this recursive task.

> Write a recursive function "cut" that takes a list and a number as argument and retuns a list containing all numbers from the list that is less than the number given in the argument.

Example:

```
>>> cut([1,5,2,8,7,4,0,9], 5)
```

`[1,5,2,4,0]`

Here is what I have come up with and its not working at all. I dont know how to make the new list or how to do the alternative if possible delete the numbers that is < given argument

```
def cut(lista, tal):

    a = 0
    if not lista:
        return a
        print a 
    if lista[0] <= tal:
       a = a + lista[0]

    cut(lista[1:], tal)
```

Any Ideas for this? I need basics, not advanced functions. I've been staring at this for over an hour now getting nowhere :s

Comment: *its not working well* be more specific - what doesn't work?

Comment: I dont know how to make the new list or how to do the alternative if possible delete the numbers that is < given argument

Comment: Why do you want to make it recursive? There are already `filter` and _list comprehensions_ which can do it in one line of code.

Comment: It has to be recursive because it says so in the instructions.. I know ways to do it without recursive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're close but you need to initialize `a` with `[]` and concatenate recursive result to `a` (what is returned from inside `cut`). Also, if you'd like to see list, first `print` then `return`. Otherwise, it's unreachable.

```
def cut(ls, n):
    if not ls:  # base 
        return []
    return (ls[:1] if ls[0] < n else []) + cut(ls[1:], n)  # peeling + rest
```

Note that in the description it's written `less than` given number but your example contains `equal` result, too. If needed, change it to `ls[0] <= n`.